# using variable with jquery selector

Tags: jquery, variables, jquery-selectors, concatenation

I have following lines of code and I want to use `visibleoffer` variable as selector. How can I concatenate it?

```
var visibleoffer = '.' + obj.parents('tbody').attr('providername') + ' .visible-offers'; //visibleoffer = .Txy .visible-offers
$(obj).parents('.Provider').find(".Offers:not(.HideByProviderFilter,.HideByMainFilter,.HideByProviderFilter.HideByMainFilter,+ visibleoffer)").length;
```

So it becomes:

```
$(obj).parents('.Provider').find(".Offers:not(.HideByProviderFilter,.HideByMainFilter,.HideByProviderFilter.HideByMainFilter,.Txy .visible-offers)").length;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to concatenate variable while building selector string:

```
$(obj).parents('.Provider').find(".Offers:not(.HideByProviderFilter,.HideByMainFilter,.HideByProviderFilter.HideByMainFilter," + visibleoffer +")").length;
```

Comment: @HumaAli: glad it helps :)